# How to load two pages dynamic in the MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have my MainWindow with a frame inside a Grid.
I want to load a Page1 inside the frame. Now I have a Button on this Page1. This Button should close Page1 and load Page2 in the frame. The second Page has also a button. With the button on Page2, I want to load Page1. And so on. If I would place the two buttons in the main window I can load both Pages, but I need the buttons separately on each page.

```
namespace PageTest
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window

    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FrameContent.Content = new Page1();
        }
    }
}


namespace PageTest
{

    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();     
        }

        private void BtnLoadPage2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}


namespace PageTest
{

    public partial class Page2 : Page
    {
        public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnLoadPage1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried to make your main window static? Or make like a `public static MainWindow mw = this;`? With that, you can access the frame from everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the code to swap pages on MainWindow.cs then you will need to define events on both pages like; PageSwapRequested. You will register to this event everytime a page is created and when a button is clicked it will trigger the event.

Something like this,

```
    namespace PageTest
    {

        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                var page1 = new Page1();
                page1.PageSwapRequested += Page1_PageSwapRequested;
                FrameContent.Content = page1;
            }

            private void Page1_PageSwapRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //TODO: swap pages and don't forget to remove Page1_PageSwapRequested event handler.
                //page1.PageSwapRequested -= Page1_PageSwapRequested;
            }
        }
    }

    namespace PageTest
    {

        public partial class Page1 : Page
        {
            public event EventHandler PageSwapRequested;
            private void OnPageSwapRequested()
            {
                this.PageSwapRequested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            public Page1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void BtnLoadPage2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                OnPageSwapRequested();
            }
        }
    }

    namespace PageTest
    {

        public partial class Page2 : Page
        {
            public event EventHandler PageSwapRequested;
            private void OnPageSwapRequested()
            {
                this.PageSwapRequested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            public Page2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void BtnLoadPage1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.OnPageSwapRequested();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. That was very helpful. All methods work great, but this was the best one for my project. Sorry for my bad English and greetings from Germany.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact a button click is a routed event to handle it in the parent frame.

```
    <Frame Name="ParentFrame"
           Button.Click="ParentFrame_Click"
           >
    </Frame>
```

Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ParentFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
    }

    private void ParentFrame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = e.OriginalSource as Button;
        if(btn == null || btn.Tag == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance((Type)btn.Tag);
        ParentFrame.Navigate(page);
    }
}
```

Button in Page1:

```
    <Button Width="100" Height="30"
            Content="Go Page 2"
            Tag="{x:Type local:Page2}"
            />
```

Page2:

```
    <Button Width="100" Height="30"
            Content="Go Page 1"
            Tag="{x:Type local:Page1}"
            />
```

However. This would be considered unsuitable for a commercial app in all the teams I've worked. It is much more usual to use MVVM and viewmodel first navigation with usercontrols presented by contentcontrols.